# In get value1 is giving the value but after get it says undefined

Tags: javascript

```
<script>  
   var value1;


        $.get("test.php", function(data){
          var mydata= $.parseJSON(data);
          value1 = mydata.value1; 


    });
       console.log(value1);

</script>
```

in my program the value1 is giving the value in $.get function but when i try to access it outside the get function scope it says undefined

Answer (score 0):

Becasue $.get is an asynchronus call. You fire $.get method and don't wait for getting response immidiately console.log will be called. if you print console.log in $.get you will get value. Read about asynchronus functions

Comment: i want the to use the value1 outside the $.get how can i do that??

Comment: function returnValue1(){
    return  $.get("test.php", function(data){
          var mydata= $.parseJSON(data);
          return mydata.value1; 


    });
}

Comment: call function
returnValue1().then(function(data){
//here you will get your data
})

Comment: i use it like this "value1 = returnValue1();"
alert(value1);
it says [object Object]

Comment: yes it is promise. you have to use returnValu1().then(function(data){
//Data will contain your value
})